# NginX - allow - custom error page

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403, deny

This is rather interesting Guys! I have the following code in one of my webapplications NginX configuration:

```
    location /login {
            #access_log off;
            proxy_pass https://public;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-Verify    $ssl_client_verify;
            proxy_set_header X-Client-S-DN          $ssl_client_s_dn;
            allow   10.0.0.31;
            deny all;
    }
```

As you can see, I wish to deny all connections to the login interface but one IP address. This works like a charm and shows standard NginX 403 error message when I try to connect from another IP. Now comes the kicker.
If I add a custom error message line THE WHOLE ALLOW/DENY OPTION IS BEING IGNORED!

I added:

```
    error_page 403 /40x.html;
```

OFC I've created a custom file to `/usr/shar/nginx/html` and the file exists. There is no error message in NginX but if I add the upper line to the webapplication config (or to the standard nginx.conf, doesn't matter) the rules I've set for allowed IPs and `deny all` is being ignored completely. What gives? Anyone has any idea how to give the users a custom NginX error page and keep the allow & deny options?

Answer (score 3):

OK, the sollution was to create not just a custom error page option, but an error page location as well. So I just had to add:

```
    error_page 403 /40x.html;
            location = /40x.html {
            root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
            allow   all;
    }
```

And voile... Damn it NginX! Why do you disappoint me so many times? :D

Comment: How did you find this solution? Was it clearly indicated in the nginx documentation or was it found using trial and error? Or perhaps something else entirely?

Comment: Google is my friend and he usually waits till I ask this community. Then suddenly another topic comes up (not really related to my issue) and there I can find my solution. I have no clue now, how did I find it or where, but was a forum topic about nginxs and ifs and locations.

Comment: A virtually identical solution is already present in the default configuration file that nginx ships with.